# TypeError: Unable to delete property. Expo Sqlite

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sqlite, npm, expo

When I click on the button then it gives me error

import React,{Component} from "react";

```
import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView ,Text, ScrollView ,TextInput, Alert, Button, View } from "react-native";

import { Card } from "react-native-elements";
import * as SQLite from "expo-sqlite";

function openDatabase() {
  if (Platform.OS === "web") {
    return {
      transaction: () => {
        return {
          executeSql: () => {},
        };
      },
    };
  }

  const db = SQLite.openDatabase("db.db");
  return db;
}

const db = openDatabase();

class AddCustomer extends Component {
  state = {
    name: null,
    
  };

  componentDidMount(){
  
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql(
        "create table if not exists addCustomer (name text );",
        []
      );
    });

  }

  addData=(name)=>{
     if (name === null || name === "") {
       return false;
     }
       db.transaction((tx) => {
     tx.executeSql("insert into addCustomer (name) values (?)", [name]);

    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Card>
          <ScrollView horizontal={false}>
         
                <View>
                  <Text>Customer Name</Text>
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    value={this.state.name}
                    onBlur={() => setFieldTouched("name")}
                    onChangeText={name=>this.setState({name})}
                    onSubmitEditing={()=>{
                      this.addData(this.state.name);
                      this.setState({name: null})
                    }}
                    placeholder="Customer Name"
                    keyboardType="text"
                  />
                  
                  <View style={{ marginVertical: 30, paddingHorizontal: 100 }}>
                    <Button
                      color="blue"
                      title="Save"
                      onPress={this.addData}
                    />
                  </View>
                </View>
           </ScrollView>
        </Card>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
          
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
  errorMsg: {
    color: 'red',
    fontSize: 15,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  button: {
    width: 150,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  }
});

export default AddCustomer;
```

> TypeError: Unable to delete property. at
> node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in
> error at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in
> reportException       at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:176:19
> in handleException      at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in
> handleError at
> node_modules\expo-error-recovery\build\ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in
> ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0 at
> node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch at
> node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:294:29 in invoke at
> node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch at
> node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:155:27 in invoke at
> node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:165:18 in
> PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0    at
> node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13
> in tryCallOne      at
> node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0 at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:248:12 in
> _allocateCallback$argument_0 at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:112:14 in
> _callTimer at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:166:14 in
> _callReactNativeMicrotasksPass at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:418:41 in
> callReactNativeMicrotasks at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:393:6
> in __callReactNativeMicrotasks at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6
> in __guard$argument_0 at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:370:10
> in __guard at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4
> in flushedQueue
>
> ```
>  Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're  %s `%s` on a released/nullified
> ```
>
> synthetic event. %s. If you must keep the original synthetic event
> around, use event.persist(). See
> https://reactjs.org/link/event-pooling for more information.,
> accessing the property, type, This is set to null at
> node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in
> error at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:84:4
> in printWarning at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:60:16
> in error at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:832:11
> in warn at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:826:8
> in get at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:276:28
> in isValidArgument  at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:305:23
> in enqueueNativeCall at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:108:8
> in Promise$argument_0 at
> node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:45:6
> in tryCallTwo       at
> node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:200:22 in doResolve      at
> node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:66:11
> in Promise         at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:107:13
> in promiseMethodWrapper at
> node_modules\expo-modules-core\build\NativeModulesProxy.native.js:15:23
> in moduleName.methodInfo.name at
> http://192.168.11.215:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:171825:27
> in exec at
> http://192.168.11.215:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:172399:33
> in runBatch at
> http://192.168.11.215:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:172441:12
> in runAllSql at
> node_modules@expo\websql\lib\websql\WebSQLTransaction.js:128:0 in
>  at
> http://192.168.11.215:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:172252:20
> in  at node_modules\immediate\lib\index.js:42:29 in nextTick
> at
> node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13
> in tryCallOne      at
> node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0 at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:248:12 in
> _allocateCallback$argument_0 at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:112:14 in
> _callTimer at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:166:14 in
> _callReactNativeMicrotasksPass at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:418:41 in
> callReactNativeMicrotasks at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:393:6
> in __callReactNativeMicrotasks at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6
> in __guard$argument_0 at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:370:10
> in __guard at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4
> in flushedQueue      PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large